# How to do numerical differentiation using Matlab?

Tags: matlab, differential-equations

Can anyone help me with doing nemerical differentiation using matlab for the function on this image:

Partial Fraction using Differentiation

[image]

Where the function F(gamma) is given by eq (11) in the following image:
F(gamma)

[image]

I have never done something like this  on Matlab, so i appreciate it if you can give me an example or try to give me the initial steps for this equation.

Answer (score 0):

A two points centered derivative could be calculated as shown in the first equation shown here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_differentiation#Finite_difference_formulas

If you want a five point centered derivative the equation that can be used is this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_differentiation#Higher-order_methods

In both cases, `h` is the step size and typical values used are lower than 10^-2.

The complete table for the coefficients is shown in a table here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference_coefficient

In matlab, you should write a function in order to evaluate it  at the interest point of the independent variable `x` and choose an appropriate value for `h`. If your using an external file, it should look like this for two points centered derivative:

`derivative=(lambda(x+h)-lambda(x-h))/(2*h)`

and the external function:

```
function[]=lambda(x,h)
    %Your function goes here: 
    %
    lambda=...
    %
end
```

Comment: Thank you, but i need the (Ls1-j) derivative as shown in the image above, not the first derivative, how am i going to change the code to enter the order of the derivative?, where Ls1 is a fixed number, it could be 2, but j is an index of a summation from 1 to Ls1.

Comment: You could code the table on the second link for higher order derivatives in a way that depending on (Ls1-j) it will use the appropriate coefficient.